# How to make a Net MAui app run in the background?

Tags: c#, maui

I am new to the NET MAUI mobile app development. I'm creating an app that scans for wifi networks nearby, and if it finds a particular network, it has to do some operations. I want this app to work even in the background, continuing to update the list of networks found and run the method I created.

How can this be done?

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to search on how to do it in android and ios - then translate that to C# - native APIs are available to you

Comment: Before you continue with your project ask yourself this: "Is one scan per half hour enough"? And if the answer is "NO", scrap it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your purpose is not to block the UI while scanning the networks, you can simply use `async/await`. Consider the following simplified code example:

```
class WifiNetworkViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public WifiNetworkViewModel()
    {
        Networks = new ObservableCollection<WifiNetwork>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<WifiNetwork> Networks { get; }

    public async Task ScanWifiNetworks()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Scanning logic here (use await)
            // When found one, add it to the Networks collection
            Networks.Add(new WifiNetwork { Name = "Wifi Network 1" });
            // Break the while loop with timeout etc.
        }
    }
}

class WifiNetwork
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To use this view model, I assume you have a list control such as `ListView` and bind it to the `Networks` property like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Networks}"/>
```

When a found network is added to the `Networks` property then the `ListView` will populate automatically. To start scanning, call the `ScanWifiNetworks()` method from a `Button` for example.

Comment: I have to find a method that allows me to run the app in the backgriud, continuing to run the network scan method, the user should see a notification that the app is active and working.

Answer (score 0):

NET MAUI itself doesn't directly support background services that run independently of the app. This is because the concept of background services in ASP.NET Core (= BackgroundService) doesn't translate well to a client application lifecycle.